# Basic Remove Event Listener Javascript

Tags: javascript, event-listener

Basically a toggle. I have this button:

```
<button id='btn'>Hover, don't click</button>
```

And this js:

```
function changeColor () {
    document.getElementById('btn').style.color = 'red';
}
```

Now:

```
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('mouseover', changeColor);
```

Worked as commanded, but:

```
document.getElementById('btn').removeEventListener('mouseout', changeColor);
```

Disobedient. 
JS Fiddle thought all are behaving correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/jimges/roq9x1os/

I disagree.
Thanks!

Comment: you are adding mouseover, and removing mouseout

Comment: @Papa, I know how to do it in CSS. I just like to learn how js controls the DOM. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @Piwakawaka, so the two then had to be identical, except that one has the removeEventListener method. I tried that but nothing happens or, should I say, only the removeEventListener is executed as I don't see any changes taking place. I guess it requires another element (another button likely) as a control "switch". Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roq9x1os/1/)

```
var btn = document.getElementById('btn')
btn.onmouseover = function changeColor() {
    document.getElementById('btn').style.color = "#ff1033";
}
btn.onmouseleave = function changeColor() {
    document.getElementById('btn').style.color = "#fff";
}
```

Or using CSS it's much easier:

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roq9x1os/2/)

```
#btn {
    color: #ff1033;
}
#btn:hover {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Huh, I didn't know you can do events directly like that. Thanks a lot! yeah, CSS is the way! :)

Comment: Yes you can and You're Welcome! :)

Answer (score 0):

Using onmouseover or css is much easier, but if you still want to do it with add Event listener, you must think that add will attach the function and remove will remove it from the element.

In any case are two separated events that you must add.

Example:

```
var element=document.getElementById('btn');
var changeColorA = function () {
    document.getElementById('btn').style.color = "#ff1033";

}
var changeColorB = function () {
            document.getElementById('btn').style.color = "#000";
}
element.addEventListener('mouseover', changeColorA);
element.addEventListener('mouseout', changeColorB);
```

Again, **I DO NOT RECOMMEND YOU USE THIS CODE, IS FOR EDUCATIONAL POURPOSES ONLY**.

Do it with CSS

Comment: Thanks @Leandro for taking the time to set examples. I do know how to do it in CSS. I only wanted to learn how js controls the DOM.

Comment: You're welcome James. Please take a second to upvote the answers useful to you and mark as response to the answer that really help you. This will increase your points and will increase your probability that other guys answer you the next time.

Comment: the site is not letting me make votes at this time. I need at least 15 reputations; currently, I only have 9, and that is up from the 4 I had last time ... though I don't know why. Know that I want to upvote each time an answer to my question is provided. Once I will reach the minimum, then yes, I will be upvoting. Thanks once more!